# React router dom v6 omits existing pathname and search while matching route

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

We have a website which has multiple apps and when an app is loaded the initial url is something like *https:abc.com/alphabet/initial/index.php?controller=index&action=index&app=learnenglish*

I've set up my ***learnenglish*** app like this

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="grammar" element={<Grammar />} />
        </Route>
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

My expectation is react router starts from this initial url as the base. But I'm getting ***No routes matched location "/alphabet/initial/index.php?controller=index&action=index&app=learnenglish"***

What am I missing?

Dependencies

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "6"
```

Comment: You have routes for `"/"` and `"/grammar"`. I don't see anything that matches anything else.

Comment: @DrewReese When I'm on `https:abc.com/alphabet/initial/index.php?controller=index&action=index&app=learnenglish`,  I want the router to match `"\"`  which should render `Layout` and `Home`.

But I get warning in console saying `No routes matched location "/alphabet/initial/index.php?controller=index&action=index&app=learnenglish"`

Comment: Are you hosting/deploying your app into some `"/alphabet/initial"` directory on the server?

Comment: Yes, its php backend which has a `.tpl` file where the app bundles get inserted

Comment: This sounds more like a server hosting/configuration issue. Read through the create-react-app [serving apps with client-side routing](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing) section. You might just need to specify a `basename` prop to the `BrowserRouter` that matches the directory where the app is deployed. You might also need to update the package.json to add a `"homepage": "."` entry. The doc explains this a bit more.

Comment: Thank you @DrewReese. Actually using <HashRouter /> without passing basename worked for me

Comment: Right, it all depends on *where* you are deploying your app and the server environment. Glad to hear it's sorted out for you. Cheers.